# difference between getGenericExceptionTypes and getExceptionTypes

Tags: java, exception, generics, reflection

I am not understanding the difference between `getGenericExceptionTypes` and `getExceptionTypes` methods in Method class of Reflection API,especially the use of former one when creating generic Exceptions is not allowed in java...

For example,

```
GenericException<T> extends Throwable{ /// NOT ALLOWED
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method m = Example.class.getMethod("method");
        System.out.println(m.getGenericExceptionTypes()[0]);
        System.out.println(m.getExceptionTypes()[0]);
    }   
    public static <T extends Throwable> void method() throws T {}
}
```

prints

```
T
class java.lang.Throwable
```

As the Javadoc for [`Method#getGenericExceptionTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericExceptionTypes--) states

> If an exception type is a type variable or a parameterized type, it is created.

and that's what's returned.

Similarly,

```
public class Example<T extends Throwable> {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method m = Example.class.getMethod("method");
        System.out.println(m.getGenericExceptionTypes()[0]);
        System.out.println(m.getExceptionTypes()[0]);
    }
    
    public void method() throws T {}
}
```

would have the same output.

So although you can't create generic sub types of `Throwable`, you can make a generic type variable with `Throwable` (or its subtypes) as its bound.

Comment: hahaha..Last line totally confused me..Thanks for the great answer..I will need to do a lot of reading before I understand it